# ParseQuery get exception all the time

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to retrieve rows from a table that has the cols:

1. objectId
2. InvitedId
3. PartyId
4. coming
5. createdAt
6. updatedAt
7. ACL

   ```
   ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("PartiesInvites");

   ArrayList<ParseObject> partiesId = new ArrayList<>();
   for (int i = 0; i < mParties.size(); i++) {
       partiesId.add(mParties.get(i).getObjectId());
       Log.d("UU-UPIL", "partyId = " + partiesId.get(i));
   }

   query.whereContainsAll("PartyId", partiesId);
   query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
       public void done(List<ParseObject> partiesInvitationsIn, ParseException e) {
           Log.d("UU-UPIL", "finding parties invitations");
           if (e == null) {
               for (int i = 0; i < partiesInvitationsIn.size(); i++) {
                   Log.v("UU-UPIL", partiesInvitationsIn.get(i).getObjectId());
               }
               mPartiesInvitations = partiesInvitationsIn;
               Log.d("UU-UPIL", String.valueOf(partiesInvitationsIn.size()));
           } else {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   });
   ```

This is the exception I'm getting

```
02-11 13:06:03.907  28398-28398/com.whoCare.noOne W/System.err﹕ com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A ParseObject subclass default constructor must not make changes to the object that cause it to be dirty.
02-11 13:06:03.907  28398-28398/com.whoCare.noOne W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.Parse$6$1.run(Parse.java:971)
02-11 13:06:03.907  28398-28398/com.whoCare.noOne W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-11 13:06:03.907  28398-28398/com.whoCare.noOne W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-11 13:06:03.907  28398-28398/com.whoCare.noOne W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
02-11 13:06:03.907  28398-28398/com.whoCare.noOne W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
02-11 13:06:03.907  28398-28398/com.whoCare.noOne W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 13:06:03.907  28398-28398/com.whoCare.noOne W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-11 13:06:03.907  28398-28398/com.whoCare.noOne W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
02-11 13:06:03.907  28398-28398/com.whoCare.noOne W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
02-11 13:06:03.907  28398-28398/com.whoCare.noOne W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-11 13:06:03.907  28398-28398/com.whoCare.noOne W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A ParseObject subclass default constructor must not make changes to the object that cause it to be dirty.
02-11 13:06:03.917  28398-28398/com.whoCare.noOne W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseObject.createWithoutData(ParseObject.java:257)
02-11 13:06:03.917  28398-28398/com.whoCare.noOne W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseObject.fromJSON(ParseObject.java:524)
02-11 13:06:03.917  28398-28398/com.whoCare.noOne W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseObject.fromJSON(ParseObject.java:499)
02-11 13:06:03.917  28398-28398/com.whoCare.noOne W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseQuery.convertFindResponse(ParseQuery.java:386)
02-11 13:06:03.917  28398-28398/com.whoCare.noOne W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseQuery.access$600(ParseQuery.java:80)
02-11 13:06:03.917  28398-28398/com.whoCare.noOne W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseQuery$6.then(ParseQuery.java:567)
02-11 13:06:03.917  28398-28398/com.whoCare.noOne W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseQuery$6.then(ParseQuery.java:558)
02-11 13:06:03.917  28398-28398/com.whoCare.noOne W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$9.run(Task.java:444)
02-11 13:06:03.917  28398-28398/com.whoCare.noOne W/System.err﹕ at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:97)
```

I tried changing the query from "whereContainsAll" to "whereContainedIn" but I keep getting the same exception. is there is anything wrong in my code !?

Comment: Put breakpoints in and see which line is causing the exception.

Comment: I did try to breakpoint the problem its in the done method. it replies with that exception up there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A ParseObject subclass default constructor must not make changes to the object that cause it to be dirty.

I'm not sure if you have a subclass from parseObject somewhere in your code that you're using to put the database entry into, but this exception is raised when you modify the item in the constructor of that subclass

From [Parse.com/android](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#subclasses)

> Ensure that your subclass has a public default (i.e. zero-argument) constructor. You must not modify any ParseObject fields in this constructor.

Comment: but I'm not using any Parse subclass in this code as you can see. :/

Comment: Are you still getting the error if you just have an empty if(e==null){ } else { e.getMessage()}?

Comment: Okay, so I'm assuming that at this point, there error might be caused somewhere else, regardless of the breakpoint. So I'll have to ask if you refer to ParseObject anywhere else? If not, could you try to comment out your entire query and see if the error still appears? If it still appears, could you show more of your source code?

Comment: Thanks for your advice ... I pin point the problem and this is how I did it

Comment: in log cat I can see which thread is running, so I made this code run on a new thread and see if the exception will show on the new thread or the main thread as usual. The result was, the exception was on the main thread which only mean that there is something wrong on one of my Parse Subclasses. I looked up my classes and I found that in one of the subclasses constructor I initialize one of the variables wrong using 


    public PartyInvites() {
        super();
        mPartyId = "";
        mInvitedId = "";
        //setmComingToParty(-1);
    }

Comment: Glad I could have been of help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
query.whereContainsAll("PartyId", partiesId);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> partiesInvitationsIn, ParseException e) {
        Log.d("UU-UPIL", "finding parties invitations");
        if (e == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < partiesInvitationsIn.size(); i++) {
                Log.v("UU-UPIL", partiesInvitationsIn.get(i).getObjectId());
            }
            mPartiesInvitations = partiesInvitationsIn;
            Log.d("UU-UPIL", String.valueOf(partiesInvitationsIn.size()));
        } else {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

To this

```
query.whereContainsAll("PartyId", partiesId);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> partiesInvitationsIn, ParseException e) {
        Log.d("UU-UPIL", "finding parties invitations");
        if (e == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < partiesInvitationsIn.size(); i++) {
                Log.v("UU-UPIL", partiesInvitationsIn.get(i).getObjectId());
            }
            mPartiesInvitations = partiesInvitationsIn;
            Log.d("UU-UPIL", String.valueOf(partiesInvitationsIn.size()));
        } else {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Basically just add an **@Override** before done method